# Can we replace the misleading [unity] tag with a more distinct tag?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

Some [unity3d](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unity3d) (game engine) questions are being accidentally tagged as [unity](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unity) (Microsoft dependency injection container).

Can we rename [unity](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unity) to [unity-container](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unity-container), and create a tag synonym for [unity](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unity) and [unity3d](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unity3d) as the Stack Overflow site has done?

See the relevant [Stack Overflow meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269701/replace-the-misleading-unity-tag-with-a-more-distinct-tag).

(There weren't too many questions tagged as `unity` to date, so I've just edited about 10-15 posts that were incorrectly categorized as [unity](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unity) to [unity3d](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unity3d).)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think this is a good suggestion. I would support it, but let's give it a few days to garner support in meta.

I would propose that we follow the convention that StackOverflow has taken like you suggested:

1. create [unity-container tag just like SO's.](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/unity-container/info)
2. Audit the current [unity](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unity) questions again to ensure that no [unity3d](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unity3d) posts remain.
3. merge all remaining posts in [unity](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unity) in to [unity-container](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unity-container)
4. create alias from [unity](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unity) in to [unity3d](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unity3d)

By sheer volumes it makes sense to alias the [unity](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unity)->[unity3d](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unity3d) as [unity3d](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unity3d) has over 140 posts, but [unity-container](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unity-container) would have only 14.

Comment: I see no downsides. Go for it.

Comment: Looks like there's adequate support

Comment: @Raystafarian - I want to wait at least for one reasonable business-day - is there a rush for this that I am not aware of?

Comment: No, just making a comment, don't see too many meta discussions here with such response in a short amount of time. I'm not advocating it be done now.

Comment: There has been no disagreement, and lots of support, so I have completed the merge/synonym